# Hibernate Restcrition Criteria OR with DetachedCritera

Tags: hibernate, criteria, restrictions, detachedcriteria

I am trying to create a detached criteria that has an OR restriction

```
    DetachedCriteria subquery = DetachedCriteria.forClass(Component.class);
    subquery.createCriteria("review").add(Restrictions.eq("owner", user));
    subquery.createCriteria("review").createCriteria("observers").
                                   add(Restrictions.eq("id", user.getId()));
```

so bascially I need to put the Restriction.or for the second and third line of the code above, however the Restriction.or does not except DetachedCritera. So I need to do something like this

```
  Restrictions.or(
        subquery.createCriteria("review").add(Restrictions.eq("owner", user)),
        subquery.createCriteria("review").createCriteria("observers").
                                   add(Restrictions.eq("id", user.getId()));
```

However this wont compile. So how do I achieve this? Any suggestions?

Thanks in advance.
cheers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
DetachedCriteria subquery = DetachedCriteria.forClass(Component.class, "component");
subquery.createAlias("component.review", "review");
subquery.createAlias("review.observers", "observer", Criteria.LEFT_JOIN);
subquery.add(Restrictions.or(Restrictions.eq("review.owner", user),
                             Restrictions.eq("observer.id", user.getId())));
```